# Is it bad practise to implement multiple function calls?

Tags: c++, overloading

Is it bad to do these things? :

"Is it bad to make functions only for calling other functions?"

```
void pyRunScript(&o_Log, &o_Dict, ModuleName, *pDictArgs = NULL)
{
    pyRunScript(o_Log, o_Dict, ModuleName, "run", pDictArgs);
}

void pyRunScript(&o_Log, &o_Dict, ModuleName, FuncName, *pDictArgs = NULL)
{ ... }
```

note:
data types ommited due to limited box width here in stackoverflow
&o_ means that this variable is for output only.

Comment: what do you mean? it works. I am only asking if it is bad to make functions only for calling other functions.

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't get it why your comment gets upvoted. This is not bad syntax or you certainly can't read. I ommited data types here to save space, not in my code.

Comment: Well, the fact that you omitted the parameter types makes the syntax invalid. It looks wrong to anyone taking a cursory glance at the code.

Comment: @juanchopanza Well, that's not my fault then. I explicitly stated the fact that I ommited them by purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it bad to have a function that only calls another function with a little more information?  Not at all, if it eliminates duplication, it's an easy way to accomplish that.

Comment: Thank you. All the answers are pretty much the same. Accepted for being the first answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, in general it is not bad to make functions that only call other functions, e.g. "call center functions," see Steve McConnell, Code Complete.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bad practice to have a function which just call different function with defaults.
but it's a bad practice to use the same name specially if it's not adding the last parameters. Not only it can be confusing for the user but also for the compiler if lets say `pDictArgs` is char*

I would just give the function name a "twist" to make it easier to distinguish:

```
void pyRunNamedScript(&o_Log, &o_Dict, ModuleName, FuncName, *pDictArgs = NULL)
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing is in fact a very good way to reuse code, where there is only a small difference between the different functions.

Perfectly good.

Edit:
Most modern compilers will inline these sort of "wrapper functions" so that it doesn't add any overhead at all. For this reason, it often make sense to put the wrapper function in a headerfile with inline so that the compiler is able to do that.

Comment: But it would be bad if I used it to return twice, right? It would get coppied twice too, wouldn't it. (That's why I used reference) Am I right?

Comment: Depends on what you are returning... (Or passing as arguments, of course). But most compilers will, given half a chance, inline these sort of things so that it doesn't make any overhead at all. It does, often, make sense to put the function in a headerfile with `inline` so that the compiler is able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

It is not bad to have a function calling just another function. However in this case I would probably do:

```
void pyRunScript(&o_Log, &o_Dict, ModuleName, FuncName = "run", *pDictArgs = NULL)
```

Comment: would it work if I I wanted to enter pDictArgs, but not funcName?

Comment: @Qwerty: nope, in this way to enter pDictArgs it is mandatory to enter FuncName first.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I made this alias function to call the other one.

Comment: @Qwerty: In this case you could move the FuncName parameter to be the last one of the list.

Comment: @Akabold well that doesn't make sense. What if I wanted to enter FuncName, but not *Args.

Comment: Could you delete this answer please? This answer is wrong. Also you did not answer my question in comments.

Answer (score 0):

not illegal but always provides some extra overhead: this is the calling a function cost, better to avoid this by trying to inline function if appropriate